# Redirect all pages to /index.php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there are plenty of tutorials about redirecting all pages to a specific domain/index.php or html page.
But I need to redirect all my pages to a ServerIP/myDirectory/ProjectName/index.php
because I work in an office which shares it's wamp to clients. so in my computer I need to go to my directory on local server and then using server's wamp.

example URL : `http://192.168.0.100/myDirectory/ePortal/index.php`

How can I do that? I have this in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteBase /myDirectory/ePortal/
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

But this htaccess is wrong. 500 Internal Error appears.

Comment: Have you tried :
RewriteRule ^/(.*)      http: //192.168.0.100/myDirectory/ePortal/index.php [L,R]
Although 192.168.0.100 is inaccessible from outside, as it's local IP.

Comment: It worked, but there's a problem with files path. for example : <img src="/captcha.php" /> doesn't work in real domains it's working.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. I wrote a framework a while back that essentially does the same thing (routes all traffic through 'index.php') and it has working static paths. You'll want to look at the `.htaccess` file in both the root and `public/` https://github.com/andyhmltn/Cherry-Framework/

Comment: The above redirects all traffic into `public/` then the `public/.htaccess` file only routes traffic to the `index.php` file if the one requested doesn't exist.

Comment: _“for example : <img src="/captcha.php" /> doesn't work”_ – well if you rewrite that to index.php as well, then you will have to handle that request inside that script as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# URLs not to redirect:
RewriteRule ^/?(captcha|My-Another-Url-Not-To-Redirect)\.php$ - [L]

# redirect all others:
RewriteRule ^/.* http://192.168.0.100/myDirectory/ePortal/index.php [L,R]

# or you may want only to redirect the homepage, then comment line above, put this:
#RewriteRule ^/index\.php http://192.168.0.100/myDirectory/ePortal/index.php [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$/? index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

This checks that the file doesn't exist before redirecting. That was, static paths still work :)